# Running files on localhost in xampp doesn't include bootstrap files

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, css, xampp

So I'm doing a project which uses bootstrap. I have my files in htdoc>DocumentRepository

```css
<link rel ="stylesheet" href ="C:\xampp\htdocs\DocumentRepository\Bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.5-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel ="stylesheet" href ="C:\xampp\htdocs\DocumentRepository\Bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.5-dist\css\bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

But the problem is running it on localhost doesn't include any of the bootstrap.
Please help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

As I guess it should be something like this in your page.

```
<link rel ="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel ="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css">
```

Keep all files extracted bootstrap file in  CSS directory.

You may also use CDN.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: CDN worked. But the path thing didn't work! It should be relative path right?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your directory structure. It is for sure something path related. If you have followed the first option , you may try `<link rel ="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Thanks! It's supposed to be just a relative path as you mentioned in here!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use or no need to include files from root drive like your linking.

```
href ="C:\xampp\htdocs\DocumentRepository\Bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.5-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css"
```

In your htdocs folder first you create a main project folder like this [Bootstrap Directory style in Htdocs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiyEM.png)

Then your folders are in the [Inside Project Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi7d9.png)

Then in the **inde.html *or* index.php** 
add link like these style

```
<link ytpe="text/css" rel="stylesheeet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And if other things are perfect then code will run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> http://localhost/2017/bootstrap.min.css

if your bootstrap or any css or jquery file inside htdose folder then you have to write http://localhost/ and then name of folder if you have inside the htdose otherwise direct write the name of file then extention

Answer (score 0):

In any linux system, when the directory starts with "/" then the location for your bootstrap file.
Thus, just add the file like src="path/file" and the should work